# Uncaught TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyNames is not a function in P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to write a class called Object in a new file with only a `constructor` and a single `show` function in the p5.js web editor. But when I am creating the Object and calling the show function in sketch.js, I'm getting the following message in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyNames is not a function`
and
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Here is the code in the three files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="object.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**object.js**

```
class Object {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  show() {
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 4);
  }
}
```

**sketch.js**

```
let object

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  object = new Object(width/2, height/2);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  object.show();
}
```

I have looked up many Stack Overflow posts and couldn't find any answer that could help. Moreover, I am not even calling the `getOwnPropertyNames` or `split` functions. Please Help!

Comment: `Object` is a native constructor you shouldn't use that as a class name in global space as it will overwrite it and other code that need to use the native `Object` will instead be using the class you defined

Comment: Oh so that's what has been creating these errors! Thank you so much you're a savior!

Comment: In that case you should accept ARTURIO's answer?

Answer (score 2):

may be p5 libraries include `Object` type
rename class for example `Object1`